# A recent change in Postgresql or Ecto regarding the ID column of a table

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm using the latest version of:

```
% psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.5
```

So far my Phoenix application has worked fine. The last time I reset my db was about 2-3 weeks ago.

Now after I've reset it, my custom psql function has started throwing an exception related "integer vs bigint for ID/primary key column".

```
 DETAIL:  Returned type bigint does not match expected type integer in column 1.
```

But it's always been integer in my app with no problem.

The thing is that I've not changed anything in the migrations related to ID columns.

Has there been any breaking changes in Ecto or Postgresql related to ID/primary key datatypes?.

**P.S.**

In all my old phoenix applications all ID columns are integers -- it's how they were generated by Ecto or Phoenix. I've not reset a db in these apps. However, in this app they're **now generated**  bigint. Why? Where can I read about this?

Comment: What is the field type in _the database_?

Comment: @mudasobwa 1st app -- bigint, others -- int.

Comment: AFAIK, `Ecto` was creating `bigint` for the autoincrement field since stone age. Are you sure your other apps have `integer` type of autoinc fields? That sounds literally very strange.

Comment: I my app all ids are `ntegers` not `bigints`. I am running Phoenix 1.3 and PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 0):

Ecto changed default type for ids to be bigint from integer. Here's the issue and PR on the Ecto Github repo, if you want to see the code and read about it:

https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1879

For general discussion you might want to create a topic at elixirforum.com.